# Display the name of the developer when we search for the website on Google

Tags: seo, google-search

I am very curious about SEO for the past few days. I noticed that when searching the Laravel website, below the website description, the name of the developer appears.

I tested three search engines, *Google,* *Bing* and *DuckDuck Go*, and only on Google does the name of the developer appear below the website description, how is this possible? I didn't see any meta tags on the website containing the name *Taylor Otwell*

**PICTURE:**

[image: IMG]

Comment: Google says that info comes from Wikipedia when I do a search for "Laravel"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you so much